# select records where value < avg() - incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I'm doing some basic exercises on NORTHWND db. I wanted to execute the following code:

```
SELECT        
    sum(SaleAmount) AS SaleAmount
    , CompanyName

FROM      [Sales Totals by Amount]

where [SaleAmount] > 
(
        Select
        avg(SaleAmount) as SaleAmount
        from [Sales Totals by Amount]
)
group by CompanyName
```

The average is equal to 4409,4948. When I'm trying to get values greater than average results are correct. When I'm trying to get values lower than average it returns values both below and above the average.
I'd be grateful if you point out where is my error.

Comment: You know that `WHERE SaleAmount >` is using the base column, not `SUM(SaleAmount)`, right? You can avoid this ambiguity by using a better alias for your expression, like `TotalSaleAmount`.

Comment: It is returning `sum(SaleAmount)`.  That amount depends on the number of rows that are in the data after applying the `where` filter.

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of values of `SaleAmount` where the *individual values* are greater than the average, or where the sum is greater than the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a filter to an aggregate formula you use the `HAVING` keyword:

```
SELECT        
    SUM(SaleAmount) AS SaleAmount,
    CompanyName
FROM      [Sales Totals by Amount]
GROUP BY CompanyName
HAVING sum(SaleAmount)  > 
(
        Select
        AVG(SaleAmount) as SaleAmount
        FROM [Sales Totals by Amount]
)
```

Comment: I'm not certain it will return the correct results. What does it mean for the `SUM()` to be greater than the average of a sale?

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with a CTE:

```
;WITH TotalSalesByCompany AS (
    SELECT SUM(SaleAmount) AS TotalSaleAmount,
           CompanyName
      FROM [Sales Totals by Amount]
     GROUP BY CompanyName
)
SELECT * 
  FROM TotalSalesByCompany
 WHERE [TotalSalesAmount] > 
       (SELECT AVG(SalesAmount) AS AverageSales FROM [Sales Totals By Amount])
```

The CTE produces a list of totals by company, and the SELECT clause selects each company whose total sales is greater than average.